# Mapping has_many and belongs_to to Active record relation object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following models:

```
Model A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
end

Model B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :c, , :polymorphic => true, :foreign_type => 'c_type', :foreign_key => 'c_id'
end
```

I want to get all the `c`s corresponding to a given `a` in the form of an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object

so basically I want to remove the following method

```
a.bs.each do |b|
  cs << b.c
end
```

since this will output an array of `c` but I want to be able to get a collection of `c` over which I can run scoping like:

```
cs.scoped(:order => :updated_at).all(:limit => 5)
```

I think I am missing some simple concept like mapping may be:

```
a.bs.map(&:to_resource)
```

or something like that.

I am running rails 2.3.14. Really appreciate help in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a [named_scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/named_scope):

```
class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :by_a, lambda { |a| {:conditions => { :a_id => a.id }}
end
```

EDIT:

I have reread your question and I think that I missunderstood you the first time. So to summarize your models look like this:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  belongs_to :c
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
end
```

You want to get all C's that are related to a given A by B, am I right? In that case what you need is a `has_many :cs, :through => :b` in your A model. So your A model would look like this:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
  has_many :cs, :through => :b
end
```

EDIT 2:

You can add has many through to the model A even if you can't modify its file including the code from a module. You can make it this way:

First make an initializer (in config/initializers) like this:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../lib/your_module.rb'
A.send( :include, YourModule)
```

Then in the lib folder make a module like this:

```
module YourModule

  def self.included(recipient)
    recipient.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  module ClassMethods
    has_many :cs, :through => :b
  end
end
```

It should work.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't change the associations since this is defined in a gem installed onto the system. I was thinking of creating an ActiveRecord::Relation instead of building an array of C. what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thinking about it and reading again I think what you are looking for is the has_many :through association.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

```
Model A < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :bs
has_many :cs, :through => :bs
end

Model B < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :a
belongs_to :c, , :polymorphic => true, :foreign_type => 'c_type', :foreign_key => 'c_id'
end
```

`a.cs` should then be accessible directly.

(**Old answer :** Not sure what you are trying to do but what about `cs.sort_by(&:updated_at)` ?)

Comment: How do you calculate cs here ? Like i calculated above ?

Comment: Yes.

But I think there is an "easier" way... I will update my answer.

Comment: Opps, didn't see that cicloon answered with has_many :through association already.